# MongoDB inserting null every 2nd time when I use .append

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm getting an error where the first time I run this code, it works 100% properly but every 2nd time after that it behaves weirdly. For some reason, the value "warnings" becomes `null` instead of `[{"warning": "Text1", "time": datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 10, 20, 2, 22, 103589)}, {"warning": "Text2", "time": datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 10, 20, 2, 50, 815495)}]` I'm using pymongo and MongoDB atlas.
This is my code:

```
                result = db.memberscol.find_one({"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id})
            if result is None or result["warnings"] is None or len(result["warnings"]) == 0:
                warnings = [{"warning": warning, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}]
            else:
                warnings = result["warnings"].append({"warning": warning, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
            db.memberscol.replace_one({"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id}, {"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id, "warnings": warnings}, 
                                      True)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the assignment operator as append returns None. That's why `warnings` becomes null in your else statement when you assign the result of append to it.
You can do it like this:

```
result = db.memberscol.find_one({"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id})
if result is None or result["warnings"] is None or len(result["warnings"]) == 0:
    warnings = [{"warning": warning, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}]
else:
    warnings = [{"warning": warning, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}]
    result["warnings"].append({"warning": warning, "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
db.memberscol.replace_one({"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id}, {"guild": ctx.guild.id, "user": user.id, "warnings": warnings},
                                      True)
```

or append to your `warnings`.

Although, same thing will work in JavaScript.